# Shared email address (parent/child)

Tags: email

One of the organisations I'm supporting has an issue with the email address fields...

They have a record for a child, and another for the child's parent(s). When it comes to sending emails they will 99% of the time be wanting to send emails to the parent, but aren't keen on having to click he relationship field to open parents record in order to get the email address.

Is there a way to share this, similar to that for postal address, or any other clever ideas to help with this?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but can't you just give the child 2 email addresses and mark the one that's the same as the parent as primary?

Answer (score 2):

- Parent's emails should be visible from the child's "Relationships" tab without actually clicking through to the parent.
- Alternatively, the [Relationship Block](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/org.wikimedia.relationshipblock) extension allows you to put the parent's info on the summary screen.  Not ideal, but it saves you a click.

After that, I think you're looking at commissioning an extension, or a modification to an existing one.  It probably wouldn't be hard to include a clickable email address via the Relationship Block extension.  Doing a "shared email" extension is pretty doable these days also, due to some under-the-hood improvements in CiviCRM 5.